# Snapchat API raising error

Tags: python, api, snapchat

I am currently experimenting with a [python API for Snapchat](https://github.com/martinp/pysnap) that was derived from the PHP API. I am running my program from a Windows 10 laptop from Asus. It seems that I am getting a consistent error that is telling me I need to update my software OS or update Snapchat, which is weird because I have the latest version of windows and there is no Snapchat on windows.

After researching the problem, it seemed it was a common message given on jailbroken phones in an attempt to counter third party developers. It seems that I am the only one having this problem, as I looked around the internet and no one else seemed to complain. Could Someone please help me get around this issue and explain why this is occurring? Thank you in advance

```
>>> import pysnap
>>> snapchat = pysnap.Snapchat()
>>> snapchat.login('username', 'password')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    snapchat().login('username', 'password')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pysnap\__init__.py", line 113, in login
    raise Exception(result.get('message', 'unknown error'))
Exception: You're using a version of Snapchat or operating system that's no longer supported. Please upgrade your device's operating system and update to the newest app version to use Snapchat. Thanks!
```

Comment: did you figure out this error? I havn't been able to find a working snapchat api myself.  if this works for you please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that I have a solution, but it looks like several similar libraries have dealt with problems as well:

SnapchatBot
https://github.com/agermanidis/SnapchatBot/issues/52

Snapchat PHP SDK
https://github.com/liamcottle/Snapchat-SDK-PHP/issues/38

It does look as though the PHP SDK solved the problem, though it doesn't look like the solution is explicitly stated there.